# Shell script error: How would I change a permission on a file in a Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I am trying to set up a cron on several AWS EC2 machines and would like to run a command on all of them at once, with the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh       
cd /etc/cron.daily
touch ecs.sh
echo '#!/bin/sh' > /etc/cron.daily/ecs.sh
echo 'sudo yum update -y ecs-init' >> /etc/cron.daily/ecs.sh
echo 'sudo yum update -y' >> /etc/cron.daily/ecs.sh     
sudo chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/ecs.sh       
cd ~
(crontab -u root -l; echo '0 0 * * * /etc/cron.daily/ecs.sh') | crontab -u root -
sudo yum update -y
```

The part that does not work is: `chmod 755 /etc/cron.daily/ecs.sh`
I am not sure, what am I missing.

Comment: What does "Does not work" mean? Like... after the script is done executing you look at the permission of that file and it's not `-rwxr-xr-x`? Do you really need to `sudo` your `chmod` command here?

Comment: @JNevill It did not function as expected.  `-rwxr-xr-x` this did not happen.

It worked without `sudo`
Is sudo not the safest way to execute commands by assuming the role of a root user or a super user?

Comment: touch ecs.sh is redundant in this script and sudo will expect you to enter a password.

Comment: If you use `sudo` it will ask you for your password, unless you've configured sudoers to allow you to do `chmod` without a password.

Comment: But since you're the owner of the file, you don't need to use superuser permissions to change the permissions.

Comment: Hi, First welcome to stackOverflow. As you notice, we seem to have a couple of questions about your question. Not to worry, this can be sorted out if you give us some more details. The main questions here are : who runs this script, is it `root` or a user? If it is not `root`, what are the permissions of `/etc/cron.daily`? Maybe the user does not have the write permission to that directory? This could explain the error. Does your user have `sudoers` rights to `chmod`? If you could provide us this information, we will gladly be of assistance.

Comment: @Alex `sudo` is like a nuclear option. It should only be used as a last resort because you are elevating the command to root user and one misstep and your system is hosed. Obviously your chmod here is pretty innocuous so going nuclear shouldn't cause harm. That being said though, if your user that is running this script has ability to create and write to that file to begin with then it doesn't need `sudo` access to `chmod` it so `sudo` is superfluous here.

Comment: @Alex My guess is that the user with which you execute this script lacks access to create a file in that directory so your `touch` and `>` redirects aren't happening and the `sudo chmod` line is pausing for user input. Is this script being run through an ssh command?

Answer (score 0):

If you can (have sufficient rights to) create a file, you do not need to `sudo` to change its permissions to `0755`. Which would also likely prompt you to input your password and run non-interactively could be the reason why the action did not take place.

On the other hand, if the user running this did not have the necessary (write) permission, preceding lines creating the file would not happen either.

You also do not need to touch a file, because that `>` redirection will create it (always a new one).

You also should not `cd` somewhere and and continue performing actions without checking directory was changed as expected. But since on all action but the unnecessary `touch` you use absolute path names, you can just as well leave out both `cd` lines.

If you clean-up the script and it still does not perform expected action, it might be useful (assuming non-interactive execution) to save its output (redirect both standard `>` (or `1>)` and error (`2>`) output to a file) and examine it for errors.